# App Engine app performance test

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jmeter, performance-testing

I have used jMeter for testing my appengine app performance.

I have created a thread group of

- 500 users,
- ramp up period: 0 seconds
- and loop to 1

and ran the test.

It created 4 instances in app engine. But interesting thing is,  **> 450 requests were processed by a single instance.**

I have ran the test again with this instances up, **still most of the requests (> 90%) were going to same instance**.

- Instance type: F1 Class
- Max Idle Instances: ( Automatic )
- Min Pending Latency: ( Automatic )

I'm getting much higher latency.
What's going wrong here? 
Generating load from 1 IP , is there any problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was totally app engine's issue...

[see this issue reported at appengine's issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7133&sort=priority&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log)

[image: Oh this is really annoying..]

Comment: This answer does not have the proper explanation. Even the link has the permission issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is you are not using a realistic ramp up value.  AppEngine, like most auto-scaling solutions, requires a reasonable amount of time to spin up new hardware. During this process *while it  is creating the new instances* latency can increase if there was a large and sudden increase in traffic.

Choose a ramp up value that is representative of the sort of spikes / surges you realistically expect to see on Production and then run the test. Use the values from this test to decide how many appEngine instances you would like to be 'always on', the higher this value the lower any impact from a surge but obviously the higher your costs.

Comment: I specified that, I ran the test again with this instances up (4 instances), still most of the requests (> 90%) were going to same instance. and giving me errors and high latency values

Comment: You might want to come at this from another direction: if you work out the highest peak you ever expect to get after you deploy this app then you can configure your test to represent that. It is basically a given (from my experience) that appEngine is not a good solution for high volume, very surgey apps and it is not designed (at all) to work well with aggressive, synthetic load tests. Note. The chances are Google are using some sort of status check to decide how to balance the load, this is _probably_ based on an interval, hence the reason you need to ramp up slowly...

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I'm getting much higher latency" what exactly are you getting? Do you consider it to be too slow?

If latency is an issue then you can reduce the max pending latency in the application settings. If you try this I imagine you will see your requests spread across the instances more.

My guess is simply that the 2-3 idle instances have spun up in anticipation of increased load but are actually not needed for your test.

Comment: for that particular test i got average latency of  approx. 10 seconds. In normal cases (without using jmeter stress testing) it averages around 50 ms. If those requests where spanned accross multiple instances, i may get much better results. I will try your solution. And let you know. Thank you.

Comment: still i have a doubt in mind, why the second test also took the same instance to run, and gave me higher latencies.!!! only few of them used others.

Comment: number of instances increased, slight change in distribution, still high latency values.!

Answer (score 0):

Spread your requests into different thread groups, and the instances will be utilised. I'm not sure why this happens. I was't able to find any definitive information that explains this.

(I wonder if maybe App Engine sees the requests from a single thread group as requests originating from a common origin, so it places all of the utilised resources in the same instance, so that the output can be most efficiently passed back to the originator of the requests.)